# Case analysis on a premise Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have the following proof state:

```
 1. ⋀i is s stk stack.
       (⋀stack.
           length (exec is s stack) = n' ⟹
           length stack = n ⟹ ok n is n') ⟹
       length (exec (i # is) s stack) = n' ⟹
       length stack = n ⟹ ok n (i # is) n'
```

How do I perform a case split on `i`? Where `i` is of type:

```
datatype instr = LOADI val | LOAD vname | ADD
```

I'm doing this for exc 4.7 of concrete semantics so this should be possible to do with tactics.

Comment: If I do `apply (cases rule: instr.induct)`, I get 3 goals, e.g:
```
 3. ⋀i is s stk stack.
       (⋀stack.
           length (exec is s stack) = n' ⟹
           length stack = n ⟹ ok n is n') ⟹
       length (exec (i # is) s stack) = n' ⟹
       length stack = n ⟹ ok n (ADD # is) n'
```
The `i` is substituted in the goal, however _not_ in the premise (!)

Answer (score 1):

If anything you should use `cases i rule: instr.cases`, but that will not work here because `i` is not a fixed variable but a bound variable. Also, the `rule: instr.cases` is not really needed because Isabelle will use that rule by default anyway.

Doing a case distinction on a bound variable without fixing it first is kind of discouraged; that said, it *can* be done by doing `apply (case_tac i)` instead of `apply (cases i)`. But as I said, this is not the nice way to do it.

A more proper way to do it is to explicitly fix `i` using e.g. the subgoal command:

```
subgoal for i is s stk stack
apply (cases i)
```

An even better way would probably be to use a structured Isar proof instead.

However, I don't think the `subgoal` command or Isar proofs are something that you know about at this stage of the Concrete Semantics book, so my guess would be that there is a nicer way to do the proof where you don't have to do any manual case splitting.

Most probably you are doing an induction on the list of instructions; it would probably be better to do an induction on the predicate `ok` instead. But then again: Where is that predicate `ok`? I don't see it in your assumptions. It's hard to say what's going on there without knowing how you defined `ok` and what lemma you are trying to prove exactly and what tactics you applied already.

Comment: there is no rule `instr.cases`, I think because `instr` is just a datatype. Doing `apply (case_tac i)` results in the same problem mentioned earlier. Fixing the variables works, I had definitely not encountered that command before. I will leave the question open for now in case there is another way to do this. I cannot do induction on `ok`: `inductive ok :: "nat ⇒ instr list ⇒ nat ⇒ bool" where
okE[simp] : "ok l [] l" |
okldi[simp] : "ok (Suc n) r m ⟹ ok n (LOADI _#r) m" |
okld[simp] : "ok (Suc n) r m ⟹ ok n (LOAD _#r) m" |
okadd : "ok (Suc n) r m ⟹ ok (Suc(Suc n)) (ADD#r) m"`